# Using case to delete data row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a simple stored procedure to update my table, but currently what I need is

```
Delete * from [ABCSystem].[dbo].[NEW_TEST_NUMBER] 
WHERE sONbr = @sONbr AND SOLine = @SOLine
```

If `@Statuscode` is = "N001" by using case. Anyone can show me a simple sample or something?

Thank you.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Testing] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@sONbr nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@SOLine nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@SerialNbr nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@StatusCode nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@PackType nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@PalletID nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@PackingListNo nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@CrDateTime nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@CrUserID nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@return nvarchar(50) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
IF EXISTS(
            SELECT sONbr , SOLine
            FROM [ABCSystem].[dbo].[NEW_TEST_NUMBER]
            WHERE sONbr = @sONbr AND SOLine = @SOLine
          )
BEGIN
    UPDATE [ABCSystem].[dbo].[NEW_TEST_NUMBER]
    SET     StatusCode = @StatusCode
            ,LastUpdDateTime = GETDATE()
            ,LastUpdUserID = @CrUserID
            ,StatusDesc = 
            CASE @StatusCode WHEN 'N001' THEN 'New'
                             WHEN 'PR001' THEN 'Prepack In Progress'
                             WHEN 'PR002' THEN 'PrePacking Completed'
                             WHEN 'WE002' THEN 'Weight Complete'
            END

            ,PalletID =
            CASE @StatusCode WHEN 'N001' THEN cast(null as nvarchar(50))
            ELSE PalletID
            END

            ,PackType =
            CASE @StatusCode WHEN 'N001' THEN cast(null as nvarchar(50))
            ELSE PackType
            END

            ,JobID =
            CASE @StatusCode WHEN 'N001' THEN  cast(null as nvarchar(50))
            ELSE JobID
            END

            ,JobCrDateTime =
            CASE @StatusCode WHEN 'N001' THEN  cast(null as nvarchar(50))
            ELSE JobCrDateTime
            END

            ,PackingListNo =
            CASE @StatusCode WHEN 'N001' THEN  cast(null as nvarchar(50))
            ELSE PackingListNo
            END

    WHERE sONbr = @sONbr AND SOLine = @SOLine

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
      Set @Return = 'UPDATE FAILED!'
    ELSE
      Set @Return = 'UPDATE SUCCESSFULLY.'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   Set @Return = 'NO DATA EXIST!'
END
```

Comment: why would you need `case`? `Delete * from [ABCSystem].[dbo].[NEW_TEST_NUMBER] WHERE sONbr = @sONbr AND SOLine = @SOLine and @Statuscode = "N001"` should do the trick

Comment: What you mean is that i just insert this statement into my store procedure?

Comment: how should i know? that is not a technical issue. from my point of view this procedure does not look like it is supposed to delete things when `@statuscode = 'N001'`, but to set lots of things to null. if you want to delete the record anyway i see no purpose in updating it first. also your update could be much simpler as you only do updates when `@statuscode = 'N001'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am seing your problem, you have to create a simple table that will tell you INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE. Link the table inside your stored proc. This will help you to sort things down.

OR

Simply sort everything in loop inside stored proc telling that

```
WHEN @StatusCode = 'N001'
DO update 

ELSE 
DO something else
```